# Как применить определенные классы для конкретной страницы?

Tags: css, firebug

Как для конкретной html страницы применить только определенные классы из общего файла стилей, отсеяв остальные? Возможно ли такое отфильтровать через Firebug?

Comment: Я не знаю, кто такой Firebug, но простое решение - взять страницу, отфильтровать ссылки grer'ом/редактором (возможно с последующей небольшой правкой) и результат использовать как вход wget (wget -i файл-со-ссылками). Возможно подойдёт и вариант "wget -I /папка-с-css нужная-страница.html"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем вопрос [закрыт] тема решена.
Кому нужно будет подобное решение, юзайте http://www.sitepoint.com/dustmeselectors/ очень удобно!